# Angular how to define return value for it to display

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-observables

I am trying to implement an autocomplete/ type-ahead function. But the following error always show: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.**  How can I define the returned result so html can display it? I'm not so familiar with frontend development :(

Thanks

**type-ahead.component.html**

```
<h1>Start Typing...</h1>

<input (keyup)="onkeyup($event)" placeholder="search movies...">

<ul *ngFor="let movie of results | async" class="card"> 
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

**type-ahead.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { switchMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Item } from '../../models/Item'
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-type-ahead',
  templateUrl: './type-ahead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./type-ahead.component.css']
})

export class TypeAheadComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Item[];
  results: Observable<Item[]> ;// this will be an array of item documents
  offset : BehaviorSubject<string|null> = new BehaviorSubject("");
  //offset = new Subject <string>();// this will be the term the user search for

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  //event handler, whenever the key is pressed we call the event, which is to check the next one
  onkeyup(e){
    console.log("e target value is like",e.target.value)
    this.offset.next(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    console.log("let see if the offest is successfully captured",this.offset)
  }

  //Observe that offset value, filter out any null value, which will throw firestore error. 
  //Reactive search query
  search() {
    return this.offset.pipe(
      filter(val => !!val), // filter empty strings
      switchMap(offset => {
        return this.afs.collection('items', ref =>
          ref.orderBy(`searchableIndex.${offset}`).limit(5)
        )
        .valueChanges()
      })
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.results = this.search();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in the code I posted, mostly due to the incompatibility of front-end and back-end codes:

In the HTML file, what follows after ngFor should be **an array of objects**, which should be defined in the TS file. But code I had is asking it to refer to "results" ( "results: Observable ") which was defined as **observable**, so cannot be displayed properly; "items: Item[]" is an array of objects but its value was never properly set, and it was not referred to in the HTML

Solution: assign values to "items" in TS, and let HTML refer to "items" for display

Code FYI:

**type-ahead.component.html**

```
<h1>Start Typing...</h1>

<input (keyup)="onkeyup($event)" placeholder="search movies...">

<ul *ngFor="let item of items" class="card"> 
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

**type-ahead.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { switchMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Item } from '../../models/Item'
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-type-ahead',
  templateUrl: './type-ahead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./type-ahead.component.css']
})

export class TypeAheadComponent implements OnInit {

  items: Item[];
  results: Observable<Item[]> ;// this will be an array of item documents
  offset : BehaviorSubject<string|null> = new BehaviorSubject("");
  //offset = new Subject <string>();// this will be the term the user search for

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  //event handler, whenever the key is pressed we call the even, which is to check the next one
  onkeyup(e){
    console.log("e target value is like",e.target.value)
    this.offset.next(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    console.log("let see if the offest is successfully captured",this.offset)
  }

  //Observe that offset value, filter out any null value, which will throw firestore error. 
  //Reactive search query
  search() {
    return this.offset.pipe(
      filter(val => !!val), // filter empty strings
      switchMap(offset => {
        return this.afs.collection('items', ref =>
          ref.orderBy(`searchableIndex.${offset}`).limit(5)
        )
        .valueChanges()
      })
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.results= this.search();
    this.results.subscribe(itemsFrmDB =>{ 
      this.items=itemsFrmDB;
      console.log("this.item: ",this.items)

    })

    }
  }
```

Comment: btw, in the end, we didn't use this for autocomplete, we implemented through <datalist> tag in HTML instead

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be `movie.title`

```
<li>{{movie.title}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't passing the correct variable. You have item, instead of movie.

```
 <ul *ngFor="let movie of results | async" class="card"> 
      <li>{{movie.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

or you can do the following

```
<ul *ngFor="(let movie of results | async) as item" class="card"> 
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```